# Pandas merge_asof displaying dates of both dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, date, merge

I would like to see the date of the "right" dataframe o column after the merge using merge_asof.

Here is a toy dataset:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Num':[1,1,2,3,3],
                  'date':['1995-09-01','1995-10-04','1995-02-07','1995-05-10','1995-05-25'],
                  'A':[42.5,40,38,40,26],
                  'B': [13.3,12.3,12.2,11,9]})

df2=pd.DataFrame({'Num':[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                  'date':['1995-09-01','1995-09-02','1995-10-03','1995-02-04','1995-02-05','1995-02-07','1995-02-08','1995-05-09','1995-05-15','1995-05-21'],
                  'C':[40.5,39.5,37.2,15,41,38,38.2,39.7,40,28],
                  'D': [13.3,12.8,12.1,12.3,13.3,12.2,12.4,12.8,11,10]}
```

I use the following for a left merge, using merge_asof (given dates on both dataframes do not always match)

```
df3 = (pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('date'), 
                     df2.sort_values('date'), 
                     by=['Num'], on=['date'], 
                     direction='nearest'))
```

This merge gives me the desired merge (prior the merge make sure you convert the date of both df1 and df2 to date (pd.to_datetime)

However, I would like the merge to also show the date of the right dataframe (**date_df2**). Therefore this is the desired output:

```
Num     date     date_df2     A        B      C       D
2   1995-02-07  1995-02-07  38.0    12.2    38.0    12.2
3   1995-05-10  1995-05-09  40.0    11.0    39.7    12.8
3   1995-05-25  1995-05-21  26.0    9.0     28.0    10.0
1   1995-10-01  1995-09-01  42.5    13.3    40.5    13.3
1   1995-10-04  1995-10-03  40.0    12.3    37.2    12.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a new column `date_df2` in the dataframe `df2` before performing a `merge_asof` operation:

```
df3 = pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('date'),
                    df2.assign(date_df2=df2['date']).sort_values('date'),
                    by='Num', on='date', direction='nearest')
```

---

```
   Num       date     A     B     C     D   date_df2
0    2 1995-02-07  38.0  12.2  38.0  12.2 1995-02-07
1    3 1995-05-10  40.0  11.0  39.7  12.8 1995-05-09
2    3 1995-05-25  26.0   9.0  28.0  10.0 1995-05-21
3    1 1995-09-01  42.5  13.3  40.5  13.3 1995-09-01
4    1 1995-10-04  40.0  12.3  37.2  12.1 1995-10-03
```